# Detecting community with python and networkx

Tags: python, networkx, modularity

I'm studying about detection communities in networks.

I'm using networkx and Python and I need to implement this algorithm: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.0476.pdf

This is how I tried to solve it:
first I make list of lists which contains as many lists (communities) as there are nodes in graph so that I can find community by index. Then for every node I find their neighbours and calculate modularity gain like this:

```
q1 = (sum_in+ki_in)/float(2*m) - pow(sum_tot+ki,2)/float(pow(2*m,2))
q2 = sum_in/float(2*m) - pow(sum_tot, 2)/float(pow(2*m,2)) -pow(ki,2)/float(pow(2*m,2))
q =  q1 - q2
```

where

```
for x in temp: # list of neighbors of node i
    sum_in += G.degree(x, weight='weight')
    sum_tot += G.in_degree(x, weight='weight')
    ki_in += weights[i, x]
    ki = G.in_degree(i, weight='weight')
```

then I find maximum q and move node I to new community.
But this doesn't work, it seems like I made mistake in formula because for large number of nodes algorithm doesn't find community.

Does anywhone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do not have access to the link you provided. (I was intended to comment, but I cannot add comment at this point)

Comment: hmm its an article called: Fast unfolding of communities in large networks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to solve this, the algorithm is already implemented in python in the [community](http://perso.crans.org/aynaud/communities/) package. You can have a look at how they made it in [the source code](https://bitbucket.org/taynaud/python-louvain).

If you do have to implement it yourself for an assignment, try to avoid the bad habit of going  on stack overflow, you learn more by finding by yourself ;)